# Foreign key which related to other foreign key choice

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

I'm trying to make the following models in django:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    client = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    loyal = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True)

class Activity(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    contact_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT,limit_choices_to={'id__in': client_id.contact_set.all().values('id').query})
```

What i want to achieve - when i creating an activity and choose client in it - i want that in contact field i have to choose only from the contacts which related to choosen client, because when i do:

```
contact_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Django allow me to choose from all the contacts. I want to limit somehow the list of contacts from i need to choose, i try this way:

```
contact_id = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.PROTECT,limit_choices_to={'id__in': client_id.contact_set.all().values('id').query})
```

But i receive this error:

```
AttributeError: 'ForeignKey' object has no attribute 'contact_set'
```

How should i do it right?

Comment: This isn't a thing you can do in the field definition. You need to define a form and do this work there.

Comment: just to say, I wouldn't call `client_id` the `Contact` field, as it sounds as an id, an integer, while this field is indeed a Client instance. And to add something more to @DanielRoseman comment, I would say that you'll need some javascript to achieve what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Can you provide any usefull link about building such kind of forms?